# Getting string where a float should be?

Tags: c, pointers, structure, printf, scanf

I couldn't find any other examples, so I'm hoping someone could point me in the right direction.  My program has to be able to handle a text file that has a list of cars,

modelname year rentalrate   <-- is how the text file is formatted.  My professor throws in a SPECIAL for the rentalrate sometimes and I need to be able to replace that with the daily special price, which is in the function call.  I use sscanf to parse the file, but my code is generating an error when I get to the SPECIAL.  Any ideas how this can be handled better?  I would really appreciate it.

```
int readCar(Car *s, float special)// function b
{
        int success;
        char *str = malloc(MAXCARS * sizeof(char));
        char *output = malloc(MAXCARS * sizeof(char));
        fgets(str, MAX_LINES, stdin);
        success = (sscanf(str, "%s %d %f",s->modelName, &s->year, &s->rentalRate));
        sprintf(output,"%f",s->rentalRate);

        if(strcmp(output, "SPECIAL")== 0)
        {
                s->rentalRate = special;
        }
        else if(success == 3)
        {
                return 0;
        }
        else
                return 1;
}
```

The below function is the function calling the above function.  Not sure if this is needed but I figured I could throw it in.

```
int readArray(Car *cars, int elemNums, float special)// function c
{
    int carCount;
    int error;
    scanf("%d", &carCount);
    if((carCount)>elemNums)
    {
         printf("\nError: Number of cars exceeds database limit.\n\n");
         exit(1);
    }
    //int i = 0;
    Car* c;
    for(c = cars; c < (cars + elemNums); c++)
    {
         error=readCar(c, special);
         if(error==1)
         {
              printf("\nError on line: %s %d $%.2f\n\n", c->modelName, c->year, c->rentalRate);
              exit(1);
         }
    }
        fflush(stdout);
        return carCount;
}
```

Comment: Just a hint: always read in a string, and only convert it to a float after you know it can be parsed as such. Don't use the `%f` specifier in `sscanf`.

Comment: Dave probably has it.  You can use [`atof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atof) to convert the string to a double.

Comment: I'm not getting an error from a compiler, just an error from my own code when the top function returns a 1.  I'm not allowed to use atof, because my professor didnt 'teach' it. Also, how can I not use %f?  &s->rentalRate is a float from the Car structure, so doesn't it have to read in a float if I'm assigning it to the structure field?

Comment: You don't **have** to read data directly into the structure. You can use a local temporary variable.

Comment: what variable can handle a string or a float?  would I have to make a char array and then parse it for a possible match to SPECIAL?

Comment: If your only options are "SPECIAL" or a float, then basically yes. Read in a string, compare with "SPECIAL", if that fails, parse a float.

Answer (score 1):

Scan `rentalRate` as a string(i.e using `%s`), to find out if it is a string or a number, check `'0' <= rentalRate[0] && rentalRate[0] < '9'` (or you can use `isdigit` from `ctype.h`), if it was a string use `strcmp` to compare it with `"SPECIAL"` else, parse it with `atof`.
Now you have a rate, obtained from parsing float or your special offer, assign this number to  `c->rentalRate`, The main point is **not scanning the number directly in `c->rentalRate` and using a string and a float temp variable before assigning final value of `c->rentalRate`**.

Since you said you should not use `atof` you can implement your own version of `atof` (That won't be so hard) or you `sscanf` instead:

```
sscanf(rentalRate, "%f", &floatRentalRate);
c->rentalRate = floatRentalRate;
```